# Allowing <tr> background color to persist with defined <td> background color/border-radius?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

JSFiddle of the offending code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnUU8/)

Specifically bits like:

```
.start{
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

I'm working on a schedule table.  The background for the entire table has a .5 alpha on the background color, so the page's background shows through.  When something is scheduled the respective  blocks are highlighted in specific colors.  The first and last of these cells have a radius.

Ideally I'd like to be able to persist the .5 alpha background in the corners, where the radius leaves some white.  I tried setting the background on the tr element, but that didn't persist (overruled by the  class).  Divs seem like a good option, but I don't want the borders between the cells (not done here for simplicity), and divs don't seem to allow for that in this case.

Comment: Bizarre. Setting it on `tr` works in Firefox and only that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `background-color` on the `table` element:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BnUU8/1/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this work on the table element and not on the table row element?  Any idea?

Comment: @ballofpopculture - Nope. Been wondering that myself for quite some time now.

Comment: due to limited browser support, also add a fallback to your table background color for non-supporting browsers. Use a background color followed by the alpha color. 'background: #777; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);'

Comment: @ballofpopculture: Looks like [none of this behavior is defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius-tables) in the context of `border-radius`, so while browser behavior is inconsistent (which it is), no one in particular is violating anything that *is* defined in spec.

Comment: I suppose that the logic of table visual model, described [in CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layers), suggests that the background of the table rows should be visible through transparent areas of table cells (like areas outside rounded corners). But it seems to work so only in Firefox 23 for me. On the other hand, "undefined behavior" of `border-radius` on cells may mean that they haven't to obey this logic, so there is no formal spec violation.